# Can/how do I split a 6/3 50amp line into a 20 amp outlet and a 30 amp outlet?

Tags: electrical, kitchens, circuit

My house has a 6/3 Cu 50 amp cable run to a junction box in the kitchen but we are changing the kitchen to have a built in oven and an induction cooktop in a different location.

The new oven is a 240v 20 amp
The new cooktop is 240v 12 amp

Can I branch the existing 50 amp junction box out to two new outlets, one for the oven, and one for the cooktop?

If so, what is required to do that from the junction box and will I need a different breaker?

Thanks!

Comment: Do your appliances have hard-wiring options?

Comment: Are you planning to put anything in front of the old junction box location?

Comment: @NoSparksPlease: I know the cooktop doesn't but I am unsure for the oven. I will take it out of the box tomorrow and take a look to report back

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I had planned on just leaving the junction box white panel there, it blends in pretty well and is very low on the wall, about a 1.5ft from the ground.

Comment: Just for for clarity be aware the NEC defines the word "receptacle" as a contact device for plug connection and "outlet" as any equipment connection, including hard-wired connections and receptacles.

Comment: @Jordan just about all built-in kitchen appliances I know of support hardwiring

Answer (score 2):

2020 NEC Section and Table 210.21(B)(3) say you must use 20A overcurrent protection for 20A receptacles, and 30A overcurrent protection for 30A receptacles, so you would need some type of accessible breaker or fuse panel to tap the existing circuit for receptacles.

However if you have the option to hard-wire your appliances and tap conductors are at least rated for 20A then the 2020 NEC 210.19(A)(3) Ex.1 says you can land ovens and cooktops together on a 50A circuit, but it doesn't allow receptacles.

This is an odd exception that allows reduced taps, for my own comfort I would change the beaker to a 40A.

Comment: Can anything be hardwired by cutting the plug off and splicing the lines?

Comment: The installation instruction are part of the Listing (by UL/ETL/CSA) and to be NEC compliant can only be installed as shown in the instructions included with the appliance.